# Problems retrieve strings with accents WSO2 DSS DataServices

Tags: encoding, utf-8, xml-parsing, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I'm testing with the WSO2 DSS tool, hoping to use it in my business.
With my first proof of concept, I'm having problems with the encoding and XML output.
I explain.

I have a table in SQL Server simple:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[USUARIOS] (
[nombre_usuario] varchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[password] varchar(20) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
[entidad_persona] varchar(60) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];
```

The DSS tool is hosted on a Windows 2003 with the DataSource properly configured.
The Data Service XML is:

```
<data name="SQLServer_FRONTAL" transports="http https">
<description>Queries Frontales_WEB</description>
<config id="SQLSERVER">
    <property name="carbon_datasource_name">SQLSERVER</property>
</config>
<query id="getUser" useConfig="SQLSERVER">
    <sql>SELECT entidad_persona FROM dbo.USUARIOS WHERE nombre_usuario = :idUser</sql>
    <result element="Users" escapeNonPrintableChar="true" rowName="User">
     <element column="entidad_persona" name="entidad_persona" xsdType="string"/></result>
  <param name="idUser" sqlType="STRING"/>
</query>
<operation name="getUser">
   <call-query href="getUser"><with-param name="idUser" query-param="idUser"/></call-query>
</operation>
<resource method="GET" path="getUser"><call-query href="getUser"><with-param name="idUser" query-param="idUser"/>
  </call-query>
</resource>
</data>
```

When I call the operation and the value of the column "entidad_persona" has accents, then I get an XML error.
If it don't have accents, then the reply is correct.

Example: If "entidad_persona" = 'Emilio **Jiménez**' then in IE or FF browser:

```
 Error de lectura XML: mal formado
 Ubicación: http://myserver:9764/services/SQLServer_FRONTAL/getUser?idUser=emiji
Número de línea 1, columna 100:
<Users xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><User><entidad_persona>Emilio Jim�nez</entidad_persona></User></Users>
```

I think the data in SQL Server are in Latin1 or ISO-8859-1 and DSS is configured to deal UTF-8.

Where Can I change the configuration of the DSS to accept responses Latin1 or ISO-8859-1?

At startup (wso2server.bat) observed that: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

In catalina-server.xml observed that URI-encoding="UTF-8"

What solutions are there to pick up the XML strings with accents?

Thank you very much for your help and for your time,

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar issue. But when I add parameter -Dfile.encoding=UTF8, then it works.

But now when I tried to execute update operation in DSS, like below, the encoding issue happens again. Still working on it.

```
     <![CDATA[
        EXEC UpdateTaskMessageByTaskId ?, ?, ?;
    ]]>
    </sql>
    <result element="updateHumanTaskByIdResponse" >
        <element name="result" column="result" xsdType="boolean"/>
    </result>
    <param name="taskId" ordinal="1" sqlType="INTEGER"/>
    <param name="messageData" ordinal="2" sqlType="STRING"/>
    <param name="lastUpdateTime" ordinal="3" sqlType="BIGINT"/>
```

Comment: Hello Richard,
I followed your comments.
It looks that way; In my case, I set the start as a Windows service, so I had to review and modify the file
**C: \ Program Files \ yajsw-stable-11.11 \ conf \ wrapper_dss.conf**
adding the following line:
**wrapper.java.additional.XXX = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8**
and it seems to work.
If I see in the future more errors or other solutions, I'll write it.

Thanks, Regards,

Comment: I made a mistake here, the variable defined in store procedure doesn't support double bits. After I change it, it works well.